# PHP 5.5.16 Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: php, exception, laravel, isset

I'm working with Laravel here (semi-irrelevant) and am running into a weird PHP issues I've not seen before. I am receiving an exception with this error:

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty

The code is in the Laravel framework (*Illuminate\View\Factory.php*), and the relevant snippet throwing the error is:

```
if (isset($this->aliases[$view])) $view = $this->aliases[$view];
```

Now, I understand if you pass an array or object in as the array key, it will throw that error. But, I dumped out `$this->aliases` and received:

```
array(0) { }
```

And dumped out `$view` and received:

```
string(11) "layouts.app"
```

So, regardless of the fact that the array is empty, a call to `isset` *should* simply return false as the string key is not set.

I don't believe this should be an error at all, but is there a setting in the php.ini that can cause such strict errors that I can change or am I just not understanding the fundamental operation of the `isset()` method?

**EDIT**

This must be related to Mihai Stancu's comment below. I just tested this and it works fine without an exception:

```
$key = 'test-key';
$test = array();
if (isset($test[$key]))
   var_dump('Yep');
else
   var_dump('Nope');
```

That outputs "Nope" as expected.

Comment: There was a weird bug on this issue regarding arrays constructed by typecasting an object to array (or viceversa) the final behavior was that it didn't recognize its members unless accessed in some particular way. I'll look for references on that.

Comment: Have you tried aliasing `$this->aliases` into another variable? Once in a while I've seen where copying process removes some oddball problem

Comment: This code is actually in the Laravel framework (installed via composer) so any changes beyond testing are moot as they will be overwritten by a composer update.

Comment: is `$this->aliases` an object that implements a `Traversable` interface? Either way: the error suggests `$view` isn't just a string. Try adding `die(var_dump($view));` just before the line that causes this error. Also show us the code where you're calling `make`, the method where this `$this->aliases[$view]` is being used. Adding `$instance->make((string) $argument,...)` might fix it

Comment: Sorry folks, I got this resolved. I must just be tired today! Turns out, that method is being called more than once in creating a view by Laravel. The first time (and the output you see above) is correct and works fine. I had an `exit;` statement after one run so it could show output without hitting the exception. I removed the `exit` and found out the second time, it was indeed passing an object in the `$view` variable. I found the problem in my code and corrected. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem here, but I had just had the same message, seemingly because I was trying to use a string key for an array, which could be cast to an int. Using the same key w/an 'a' in front of it to enforce stringness seemed to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I think it tends to be "bad practice" to use integers as string keys in an associative array due to that exact problem.

Comment: Please post your answer as an "answer", not as an edit to your "question". It makes it easier to find. Plus, then I can upvote it :)

Answer (score -2):

Simply declare `$something = aliases[$view]` and parse it as a string and then

```
if (isset($this->$something))
```